# Seeking old story about invention/"repair" of a time machine

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, time-travel

I recall (from 40-50 years ago) a story (no source, but probably not online or movie) about a scientist/technician that is asked to "repair" a time machine that s/he is told did work, but is now broken.  Unbeknownst to him/her, it (actually a random pile of parts) had never worked and the employer is simply trying to bolster their motivation.  S/he succeeds in "repairing" it, thus inventing a time machine.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Are you sure it's a time machine?  There's a famous story in this vein where the scientists are tricked into inventing an antigravity device.

Comment: Indeedly; [Noise Level" by Raymond F. Jones](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/182193/government-investigating-home-library-of-missing-inventor)

Comment: Also a little bit similar to Double Dare, by Robert Silverberg. In that case it was a perpetual motion machine. And an anti-gravity device. https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/74090/scientists-shown-a-fake-anti-gravity-device-to-motivate-them-to-build-the-real-t/106780#106780

Comment: Actually, I'm not sure it was a time machine.  I'll check those suggestions out.  Thank you.