# Scientists tricked into inventing antigravity story?

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

A short story I read somewhere, possibly Analog Magazine.
The US government assembles a team of Scientists to reverse engineer a wrecked antigravity backpack.
The word 'noise' is in the title.
It turns out the film of it working was faked.
The government thought that there was no progress in antigravity research because of the bias that it was impossible.

Comment: You might look through [these search results](http://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/adv_search_results.cgi?USE_1=title_title&O_1=contains&TERM_1=noise&C=AND&USE_2=title_ttype&O_2=exact&TERM_2=SHORTFICTION&USE_3=title_title&O_3=exact&TERM_3=&USE_4=title_title&O_4=exact&TERM_4=&USE_5=title_title&O_5=exact&TERM_5=&USE_6=title_title&O_6=exact&TERM_6=&ORDERBY=title_copyright&ACTION=query&START=0&TYPE=Title)

Comment: I seem to remember something called "White Noise", but I can't remember who wrote it.

Comment: probably the same as https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/182193/government-investigating-home-library-of-missing-inventor

Answer (score 18):

The story is ["Noise Level"](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?55972) (1952) by Raymond F. Jones, first published in Astounding Science Fiction, December 1952 (Vol. 40, no. 4).  [Original text](https://archive.org/details/Astounding_v50n04_1952-12_Gorgon776/page/n7) is available at the Internet Archive.

Inspired by John Campbell himself!

Comment: Huh. This is at least the third time this one has come up, but yours might be the first accepted answer, once you do so in 47 hours. :) How did you find it?

Comment: It's quite a memorable story.  (I read it decades ago in an anthology, but remembered it and looked it up more recently.  In fact, I knew it from the question title alone, and was quite disappointed to find someone's beaten me to it!)

Comment: Thank you! I read this - many years ago! - and would like to read it again :)