# Short story: Mindset of believing something is possible (even if not true) influences the outcome

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, artificial-gravity

Trying to find what I think was a short story, probably written 30 or more years ago.  Synopsis, to the best of my recollection:  Organization (military?/government?/corporate?) shows film of an inventor demonstrating successful flight of an "anti-gravity" device.  Film ends with the device totally destroyed and the inventor dying in the disaster.

The film is shown to a group of sceptical scientists who are convinced by its provenance that the film is genuine.  The scientists are then given access to the inventor's home and lab which contain papers, books, articles, etc. relating to a melange of documented levitation occurrences, UFO sightings, paranormal occurrences, etc. - but no details of the inventor's solution except very general miscellaneous piecemeal notes, calculations and drawings.

Because the scientists are convinced that a solution does exist - as demonstrated by the film they have been shown - they work to duplicate the inventor's route to solving "anti-gravity".  They are successful ... but are then told that the original film was a hoax.

Answer (score 4):

This is probably "Noise Level" by Raymond F. Jones as per [Government investigating home library of missing inventor](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/182193/government-investigating-home-library-of-missing-inventor).

> Many of the country's top physicists are gathered together and are shown film of the inventor hovering using some sort of small anti-gravity device. They are told that, unfortunately, he shortly after died in a crash and is unit was completely destroyed. The government scientists can't make sense of the records he left behind, so they are asked to figure out what he did.
>
> His lab is filled with odd stuff -- some high tech, some assorted, plus books on physics as well as the occult. A real mishmash.
>
> The scientists persevere and, knowing the antigravity is possible, eventually come up with a huge, clumsy device that nevertheless hovers. They are then introduced to the (live) inventor -- who turns out to be an actor. They are told that this was an experiment to see if they could achieve more if they were forced to think outside the box.
>
> It was first published in Astounding Science Fiction, December 1952 and has been widely reprinted: https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?55972

It can be read freely in the Internet Archive at https://archive.org/details/Astounding_v50n04_1952-12_Gorgon776

Comment: Thanks, FuzzyBoots ... this is definitely the story I was looking for !!!  It was brought to mind by all the hoo-haa around the recent publication of US Military "verified" videos of UFO activity plus the recent patent application, also by the US Military for an "anti-gravity" or "inertia-cancelling" method of propulsion ... Maybe they're using the same psychological manipulation as proposed in Raymond F. Jones' story ... ???  :-)

Comment: @Carter: That's good enough for me to vote to close. :) Feel free to accept as well if you wish, but it's not necessary.